# LSTM Tensorflow model not taking sequences into account

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm

I've been struggling with this pet problem for a while now, so any help would be appreciated!

I have a csv file, with a few random columns, and a final column that's based on the sum of the last few values from the first column. I'm trying to use an LSTM model to capture this structure, i.e. to predict the last column given the first few.

Here's the model I've been using:

```
# Generate test data

train_input = train_input.reshape(m, n_input, 1) # is nr of rows, n_input is number of input columns

NUM_EXAMPLES = int(m * training_size)

test_input = train_input[NUM_EXAMPLES:]
test_output = train_output[NUM_EXAMPLES:]

train_input = train_input[:NUM_EXAMPLES]
train_output = train_output[:NUM_EXAMPLES]
#
# # Design model
#
data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_input, 1])
target = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])

num_hidden = 24
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(num_hidden, state_is_tuple=True)

val, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, data, dtype=tf.float32)

val = tf.transpose(val, [1, 0, 2])
last = tf.gather(val, int(val.get_shape()[0]) - 1)

weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([num_hidden, int(target.get_shape()[1])]))
bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[target.get_shape()[1]]))

prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)

cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(target * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(prediction,1e-10,1.0)))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
minimize = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

mistakes = tf.not_equal(tf.argmax(target, 1), tf.argmax(prediction, 1))
error = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(mistakes, tf.float32))

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init_op)

no_of_batches = int(len(train_input)/batch_size)
for i in range(epoch):
    ptr = 0
    for j in range(no_of_batches):
        inp, out = train_input[ptr:ptr+batch_size], train_output[ptr:ptr+batch_size]
        ptr+=batch_size
        sess.run(minimize,{data: inp, target: out})
    print("Epoch - {}".format(i))
incorrect = sess.run(error,{data: test_input, target: test_output})
print('Epoch {:2d} error {:3.1f}%'.format(i + 1, 100 * incorrect))
sess.close()
```

I've tried several spreadsheets with random numbers, and I'm consistently getting around 83% error rate. On the other hand, this algorithm CAN learn if the target column is not sequential.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't clearly get your point, do you mean you have a csv file like this?

```
x1   x2   x3   x4   ... xn
v11  v21  v31  v41  ... vn1
v12  v22  v32  v42  ... vn2
...
v1n  v2n  v3n  v4n  ... vnn
y1   y2   y3   y4   ... yn
```

And `yn` based on `sum(vn1+...+vnn)`? Like `a * sum(V) + b`?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, yn is based solely on the last 5 entries in the x1 column. The first four entries in yn are 0, after that it's yn = x1(n-5) + x1(n-4) ... + x1n